# Filtering on Angular 6 mat-select values not resetting original array

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am filtering an array on the multiple selections from a `mat-select`. The filtering works fine except if I select an option and then deselect it the entire array is removed from the UI. If I then select a few options, those array elements will be shown. This doesn't happen with the search field input I have in the same UI.

HTML:

```
<article *ngIf="monitors">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
  <mat-card class="filters">

    <mat-form-field class="search">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Search Monitors" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="searchTerm" matSuffix mat-icon-button
        aria-label="Clear" (click)="searchTerm=''">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="categories">
      <mat-select placeholder="Filter categories" [formControl]="categories"
        (selectionChange)="filterCategories($event.value)" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categoriesList" [value]="category">{{category}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

  </mat-card>

  <mat-card class="list">
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let monitor of monitors | filter: searchTerm; last as last">
          <h2 class="topic" mat-line>{{monitor.topic}}</h2>
          <h4 class="description" mat-line>{{monitor.queryDescription}}</h4>
          <div class="categories" mat-line>
            <span *ngFor="let category of monitor.categories">
              {{category.value}}
            </span>
          </div>
          <mat-divider [inset]="true" *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </mat-list>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</article>
```

TS:

```
export class MonitorsComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Monitors';
  monitors: IMonitor[];
  originalMonitors: IMonitor[];
  searchTerm: string;
  categories = new FormControl();
  categoriesList: string[];
  selectedCategories: string[];

  constructor(private monitorService: MonitorsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMonitors();
  }

  filterCategories(categories: string[]) {
    this.monitors = this.originalMonitors.filter((monitor: IMonitor) => {
      return categories.some((category: string) =>
        monitor.categories.map((c: ICategory) => c.value).includes(category),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

I get the same results when using a pipe.
How should I reset the original array after options have been deselected?

**EDIT:** Here's a Stackblitz to illustrate my problem - https://angular-yehvm6.stackblitz.io
**EDIT:** And the editor - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yehvm6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your click handler to this:

```
 filterPizzas(toppings: string[]) {
    if(toppings && toppings.length >0){
          this.pizzas = this.originalPizzas.filter((pizza: IPizza) => {
      return toppings.some((topping: string) =>
        pizza.toppings.indexOf(topping) >= 0,
      );
    });
    }else{
      this.pizzas = [{ name: 'Cheese Supreme', toppings: ['Extra cheese'] }, { name: 'Meat Feast', toppings: ['Pepperoni', 'Sausage'] }, { name: 'Pizzazz', toppings: ['Extra Cheese', 'Pepperoni', 'Onion'] }]
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thankyou @NicoLA it was the `toppings.length` check I was missing, fundamental JS screw up, couldn't see it for the friday end of day frustrations! Thanks!